# Match single custom host inventory variable when using multiple nested host variables

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to loop through matched hosts in an inventory file where each host has certain variables, but, each host might have multiple nested variables associated with it, like this below:

### inventory file:

```
[support]
myhost1 application_role="['role1', 'role2']" team="['ops', 'dev']"
myhost2 application_role="['role1']" team="['ops', 'sales']"
```

My goal is to try and deliver a file to only the hosts that match the customer variable key "team" equal to value "sales".

I'm testing with this test task just to get some response but as you can see from the output, it is skipping all of them because it's not catching the nested variable, it seems to be reading the variable as one whole string and not splitting?

### test task:

```
- name: Loop through example servers and show the hostname, team attribute
  debug:
    msg: "team attribute of {{ item }} is {{ hostvars[item]['team'] }}"
  when: hostvars[item]['team'] == "sales"
  loop: "{{ groups['support'] }}"
```

### output:

```
PLAY [support] ************************************************************************

TASK [ssh_key_push : Loop through example servers and show the hostname, team attribute msg=team attribute of {{ item }} is {{ hostvars[item]['team'] }}] ***
skipping: [myhost1] => (item=myhost1) 
skipping: [myhost1] => (item=myhost2) 
skipping: [myhost1]
skipping: [myhost2] => (item=myhost1) 
skipping: [myhost2] => (item=myhost2) 
skipping: [myhost2]
```

I'm not sure how to get ansible to read a single nested variable from the host inventory.

Comment: I ended up creating a new variable called team_name in vars/main.yml and issuing the team name at the command line with extra vars, then using this task to avoid the jinja2 warning about conditionals and {{ }}:
```
- name: Loop through example servers and show the hostname, team attribute
  debug:
    msg: "team attribute of {{ item }} is {{ hostvars[item]['team'] }}"
  when: hostvars[item]['team'] is contains (team_name)
  loop: "{{ groups['support'] }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```yaml
when: hostvars[item]['team'] == "sales"
```

This expression is comparing a list e.g.

```yaml
team:
 - ops
 - sales
```

to a single string value `sales`. This will always return false.

What you want to do is [check if the list contains that value](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#test-if-a-list-contains-a-value). As explained in this link, Jinja2 provides an `in` test, but ansbile provides `contains` which can ease writing in some cases. Both versions are equivalent:

```yaml
when: hostvars[item]['team'] is contains 'sales'
# or
when: "'sales' in hostvars[item]['team']"
```

Comment: Very cool, this does work to hit the single nested variable.  I wanted to ask another question while I"m here I guess, do you know why the loop would seem to be looping twice?  I have two entries in my inventory... I'm guessing that's why but, never seen that before

ok: [host] => (item=host) => {}

MSG:

team attribute of host: host contains team: ['dev']
skipping: [host] => (item=host) 
ok: [host] => (item=host) => {}

MSG:

team attribute of host: host contains team: ['dev']
skipping: [host] => (item=host) 
ok: [host] => (item=host) => {}

Comment: Please take the time to read the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and understand the rules around here. Ask an other question and try to make it [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)